# Need help creating a model in a view

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Match(models.Model):


    match_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    player = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=match_game, default=2)
    time_start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=None, null=True)
    match_finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('match:details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.match_name

class PlayerSignup(models.Model):
    current_player = models.ForeignKey(User)
    signup = models.ForeignKey(Match)
```

urls.py

```
 url(r'^create/add/$', views.MatchCreate.as_view(), name='match-add'),
 url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(template_name = 'match/bracket_detail.html'),  name='details'),
 url(r'^search/$', views.IndexView.as_view(template_name = 'match/bracket.html'), name='search'),
 url(r'(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.PlayerSign, name='join')
```

views.py

```
def PlayerSign(request):
    model = PlayerSignup.objects.all()
    match = Match.objects.get(pk=Match.pk)

    joinmatch = PlayerSignup(current_player=request.user, signup=match)
    joinmatch.save()

    return render(request, 'match/bracket_detail.html', {'model': model })
```

template

```
 <a href="{% url 'match:join' match.pk%}">Join Match</a>
```

when a person clicks on the 'Join Match' link i would like it to create a PlayerSignup model and link it to the current match that they are on.

when i click the Join Match link nothing happens, no new model, no error

Comment: What are your other urls?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i edited , all the URLs should be in there

Comment: Well what is your join match link?

Comment: How are you expecting Django to tell the difference between your details and join URLs?

Comment: @DanielRoseman ahh i see what you mean. adding /add/ to the end gave me a 'NoReverseMatch' error

Comment: Can you show the full error please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to edit this statement

```
def PlayerSign(request):
    ...
    match = Match.objects.get(pk=Match.pk)
```

to

```
def PlayerSign(request, pk):
    ...
    match = Match.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

Because there is an request parameter in URL named pk, you should pass this parameter to the query method.

Second, review your url define

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(template_name = 'match/bracket_detail.html'),  name='details'),
url(r'(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.PlayerSign, name='join')
```

Change to

```
url(r'^match_detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(template_name = 'match/bracket_detail.html'),  name='details'),
url(r'^player_detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.PlayerSign, name='join')
```

Comment: That is indeed *a* problem, but not the one the OP is experiencing: Django is not even getting to the relevant view because of a URL conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! just wondering one thing, what if i dont want to go to a new url but stay on the same url? @ThinhPhan

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what you mean. But I guess you need to use "HttpResponseRedirect" (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial04/)